# Camera rotation axes in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I adapt this code so that it controls not only the y-axis but also the x-axis?

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 120f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float yRotation = 200f;
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        yRotation -= mouseY;
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -25f, 20f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);

    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add another variable (`float xRotation`) and in the `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0f, 0f);` change the second value to `xRotation`. Looking at the documentation (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html), the first value is the x rotation so you are actually using the `yRotation` value to change the x rotation. Either way, to add another axis just add another variable and add it to the last line in your code.

Your final code would look something like this assuming you are going to change the second value the same way as the `yRotation` variable.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    float speed = 120f;
    public Transform playerBody;
    float yRotation = 200f;
    float xRotation = 200f;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.left * mouseY);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
        yRotation += mouseY;
        xRotation += mouseX;
        yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -25f, 20f);
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -25f, 20f);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);

    }
}
```

This code is also quite old as it uses the old Unity Input System. Unity has come out with a new Input System that is much better than the old one and comes with much more customisation. I would recommend you take a look at it. Here is the documentation if you want to have a quick read on how to get started https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html. They also have a few videos on their YouTube channel which you might find helpful as well.

Comment: why is it that when I move the mouse to the left, the camera moves to the right and vice versa? (when using this code)

Comment: @MiDem This is likely a problem with the original code as I just added a line for the xRotation. I haven't tested it out myself but I am guessing that you should make `yRotation += mouseY;` and `xRotation += mouseX;`. If this works please let me know so that I can edit the code in my answer.

Comment: thanks you for you reply! for me work this: xRotation += mouseX;
        yRotation -= mouseY;